# Specialize function if argument has member variable

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, template-specialization, gcc4.6

I have a function for error reporting that is templated because it can report errors for many different message classes:

```
template <typename MSG>
void reportErr(const MSG& msg)
{
    std::cout << "ERROR: " << msg.error << std::endl;
}
```

However, some types of message have more detailed error that can be reported or other specialized error reporting, e.g.

```
template<>
void reportErr(const SpecificMsg& msg)
{
    std::cout << "ERROR: " << msg.error;
    std::cout << ", details: " << msg.details << std::endl;
}
```

Since there are many types like `SpecificMsg`, I'd rather not create an individual template specialization for each type. Is it possible to create a generic specialization/partial specialization for any type that has a `.details` member variable?

If possible, I'd like a way to do this generally (so one specialization if it has `.details`, a different one if it has `.other_info`, etc).

**Edit**: This is explicitly asking about *functions*. I've seen code that does similar things to specialize template *classes*, but I've never encountered something that does what I want for non-member functions. I suspect it isn't hard to convert the approach used for classes to work for functions, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

**Edit 2**: my version of gcc (4.6.3) appears not to support the full C++11 standard, so the [`void_t`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4436.pdf) option mentioned in the "duplicate" question doesn't work for me. My compiler complains "expected nested-name-specifier before 'type'" etc and won't even let me define void_t. As such, I've removed the C++11 tag from my question.

Comment: I vote to reopen this question. Even though specializing a template based on whether a specific member exist is a way to answer OP's question, it is not the only one.

Comment: It is almost exactly the same with functions. One just needs to make a helper template class.

Comment: I think it's fair to ask if it's possible to do _without_ the helper class. It may be that it's not possible, but simply marking this as duplicate doesn't answer that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If possible, I'd like a way to do this generally (so one specialization if it has .details, a different one if it has .other_info, etc).

If I got your expectation, you can use the `choice`-trick combined with `decltype` as it happens in the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N>
struct choice: choice<N-1> {};

template<>
struct choice<0> {};

struct Foo { int error; };
struct Bar { int error; int details; };
struct Quux { int error; char other_info; };

template<typename MSG>
auto reportErr(choice<2>, const MSG& msg) -> decltype(msg.details, void()) {
    std::cout << "ERROR: " << msg.error;
    std::cout << ", details: " << msg.details << std::endl;
}

template<typename MSG>
auto reportErr(choice<1>, const MSG& msg) -> decltype(msg.other_info, void()) {
    std::cout << "ERROR: " << msg.error;
    std::cout << ", other_info: " << msg.other_info << std::endl;
}

template <typename MSG>
void reportErr(choice<0>, const MSG& msg) {
    std::cout << "ERROR: " << msg.error << std::endl;
}

template <typename MSG>
void reportErr(const MSG &msg) {
    reportErr(choice<100>{}, msg);
}

int main() {
    reportErr(Foo{0});
    reportErr(Bar{0, 42});
    reportErr(Quux{0, 'c'});
}
```

See it up and running on [`wandbox`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pEuKYQhYyttgYwW1) (using GCC 4.5.4 actually, the version you mentioned isn't available). It exploits overloading resolution to pick up a *working version* of the function according to the type of the message and discards all what's in between. You can add more *specializations* (let's call them so, even though they are not properly *specializations* after all) and sort them according to your preferences by adjusting the `choice` parameter as needed (the higher its value, the higher the priority of the *specialization*).

---

Something similar can also be done by combining the `choice`-trick with `sizeof` in a SFINAE'd based solution similar to what I shown above.
In particular, here is a working example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N>
struct choice: choice<N-1> {};

template<>
struct choice<0> {};

struct Foo { int error; };
struct Bar { int error; int details; };
struct Quux { int error; char other_info; };

template<typename MSG, std::size_t = sizeof(MSG::details)>
void reportErr(choice<2>, const MSG& msg) {
    std::cout << "ERROR: " << msg.error;
    std::cout << ", details: " << msg.details << std::endl;
}

template<typename MSG, std::size_t = sizeof(MSG::other_info)>
void reportErr(choice<1>, const MSG& msg) {
    std::cout << "ERROR: " << msg.error;
    std::cout << ", other_info: " << msg.other_info << std::endl;
}

template <typename MSG>
void reportErr(choice<0>, const MSG& msg) {
    std::cout << "ERROR: " << msg.error << std::endl;
}

template <typename MSG>
void reportErr(const MSG &msg) {
    reportErr(choice<100>{}, msg);
}

int main() {
    reportErr(Foo{0});
    reportErr(Bar{0, 42});
    reportErr(Quux{0, 'c'});
}
```

See it up and running on [`wandbox`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JDGSf5cRcsGXuFg9). The advantage is that this solution doesn't suffer from the annoying warning you receive with the previous one.

---

I tested it with an older compiler than what you asked (GCC 4.5.4), so I'm pretty confident they both work also with GCC 4.6.x.

Comment: I really like that priority/choice trick. It looks more of a hack, but for C++03 compilers I cannot imagine simplest.

Comment: @YSC Well, it's a way to exploit overloading, I wouldn't say _a hack_. After all, this is what our language offers and there are cases where this trick is useful even if you're using C++17. The fact is that with C++17 you have several solutions from which to choose, with C++11 only partially implemented you have much less freedom. :-)

Answer (score 5):

I'd use SFINAE for this. First, let's define two functions, which return error a string for a message:

```
namespace detail
{
    // for messages with "details" member:
    template<typename MsgType>
    std::string makeMsgString(const MsgType& msg, decltype(MsgType::details)*)
    {
        return "Error: " + msg.error + ", details: " + msg.details;
    }

    // for messages without "details" member:
    template<typename MsgType>
    std::string makeMsgString(const MsgType& msg, ...)
    {
        return "Error: " + msg.error + ", no details";
    }
}
```

Now, these functions can be used like that:

```
struct NonSpecificMsg { std::string error; };
struct SpecificMsg { std::string error, details; };

template<typename MsgType>
void reportErr(const MsgType& msg)
{
    std::cout << detail::makeMsgString(msg, nullptr) << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    reportErr(NonSpecificMsg { "some error" }); // 1
    reportErr(SpecificMsg { "some other error", "some details" }); // 2
    return 0;
}
```

What happens here?

Call 1): `NonSpecificMsg` does not have a `details` member, therefore the first overload does not exist. Since `MsgType::details` does not exist, `decltype(MsgType::details)*` is not a valid type. SFINAE causes this definition to be ignored instead of throwing an error during compilation.
There's only overload 2), which does not access `details` member.

Call 2): `SpecificMsg` has `details`, so both overloads are considered by a compiler. However, variadic function overloads (the second one) always have lower priority than any other matching overload, so the first one is chosen.

**Edit:** this is a C++11 solution. Unfortunately, `decltype` was introduced in GCC 4.8.

**Edit 2:** It turns out that `decltype` **can** be used with GCC 4.6 (it was introduced with version 4.3). Version 4.8.1 changed its semantics, but in OP's case, previous versions will work - see [GCC's C++ status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html)

Comment: You can use the `typeof` gcc extension, and use `0` instead of `nullptr` to make it work together with this old compiler. https://godbolt.org/g/DLEhrP

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, @Rudi. Actually, code I've posted works with 4.6 (when you add `-std=c++0x`). Updated my answer accordingly. It would seem that this solution would work with C++03 compiler with `typeof` extension (or equivalent, I think that MSVC has had `decltype` before C++11).

Comment: Surprisingly, this isn't actually working with my gcc 4.6.3 cross-compiler. It compiles just fine, but it calls the variadic/non-specific overload regardless of whether the details field exists! Seems like that's possibly just a bug in 4.6.3 since it works just fine in later versions

Comment: Update: if I cast NULL to be a pointer to std::string, then it works as intended...

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This is a C++17 answer written before OP specified their gcc/c++ version. I let it there to hopefully help others*.

You can tag your message types and test those tag at compile time:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

struct HasErrorMember { std::string error = "error"; };
struct HasDetailsMember { std::string details = "details"; };

template<class MSG>
void reportErr(const MSG& msg)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<HasErrorMember, MSG>)   std::cout << "ERROR: " << msg.error;
    if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<HasDetailsMember, MSG>) std::cout << ", details: " << msg.details;
    std::cout << "\n";
}

struct MsgSimple : HasErrorMember
{};

struct MsgDetails : HasErrorMember, HasDetailsMember
{};

int main()
{
    MsgSimple  ms;
    MsgDetails md;
    std::cout << "error only:\n";
    reportErr(ms);
    std::cout << "error + details:\n";
    reportErr(md);
}
```

Accordingly to your needs, those tag can embed the members themselves or can be empty, putting the responsibility to ensure member<->tag consistency to the developer.

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2614443254bf54e)

Comment: @elvis.dukaj yeah, at the time this answer was written, it was not a requirement yet. I leave it anyway because it could help others.

Answer (score 0):

With only C++03, traits is more verbose than with C++11 (as [`std::is_detected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected)), you might do something like:

```
#define DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(traitsName, funcName, signature)               \
    template <typename U>                                                   \
    class traitsName                                                        \
    {                                                                       \
    private:                                                                \
        template<typename T, T> struct helper;                              \
        template<typename T>                                                \
        static char check(helper<signature, funcName>*);                    \
        template<typename T> static int check(...);                         \
    public:                                                                 \
        static                                                              \
        const bool value = sizeof(check<U>(0)) == sizeof(char);             \
    }
```

then

```
// Would be in std in C++11
template <bool, typename T = void> struct enable_if
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T> struct enable_if<false, T>
{
};
```

and then

```
DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(has_details, &T::details, std::string (T::*));

template <typename MSG>
typename enable_if<!has_details<MSG>>::type
reportErr(const MSG& msg)
{
    std::cout << "ERROR: " << msg.error << std::endl;
}

template <typename MSG>
typename enable_if<has_details<MSG>>::type
void reportErr(const MSG& msg)
{
    std::cout << "ERROR: " << msg.error;
    std::cout << ", details: " << msg.details << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72697f8ee0ed05eb)