# Check if a class has a method with a given name but any signature

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, methods, sfinae

I'm trying to find a way to simply check if a method of a given name exists in a c++ class using c++11 features, but without(!) checking the signature.

I was unable to find anything without the signature check, so I tried to use Valentin Milea's solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87372/check-if-a-class-has-a-member-function-of-a-given-signature/10707822#10707822) and modify it (see below), but my understanding of c++ is not deep enough to really grasp what's going on there:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class C>
class HasApproxEqualMethod
{
    template <class T>
    static std::true_type testSignature(bool (T::*)(const T&, double) const);

    template <class T>
    static decltype(testSignature(&T::approx_equal)) test(std::nullptr_t);

    template <class T>
    static std::false_type test(...);

public:
    using type = decltype(test<C>(nullptr));
    static const bool value = type::value;
};

class Base {
public:
virtual ~Base();
virtual bool approx_equal(const Base& other, double tolerance) const;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
     // same interface as base class
    bool approx_equal(const Base& other, double tolerance) const;
};

class Other {};

static_assert(HasApproxEqualMethod<Base>().value == true, "fail Base");
static_assert(HasApproxEqualMethod<Other>().value == false, "fail Other");
 // this one fails:
static_assert(HasApproxEqualMethod<Derived>().value == true, "fail Derived");
```

I think the root of the problem is that my `approx_equal` uses base class references also in the derived class(es) and that doesn't match the signature anymore.

In the end, I want to construct a template comparison function that calls `approx_equal` if it exists, or something else( e.g. `==` for strings etc., or `fabs(a-b) <= tolerance` for floats and doubles). The approx_equal functions will then in turn call the template comparison for each member.

I actually got that part to work with an ugly workaround, where each class with an `approx_equal` method also gets a member variable `const static char hasApproxEqualMethod`. Then I check if that variable exists as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50295630/specialize-function-if-argument-has-member-variable), but that's certainly not the way to go.

Comment: The answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393938/find-out-whether-a-c-object-is-callable/15396757#15396757) should come handy. Just replace `operator()` with `approx_equal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you check that a class has method that accept, as first argument a constant reference to an object of the same class

```
template <class T>
static std::true_type testSignature(bool (T::*)(const T&, double) const);
// .......................................^...........^   same class
```

but inside `Derived` you define a method that receive an object of a different class (`Base`)

```
// ...VVVVVVV  object is Derived
class Derived : public Base {
public:
     // same interface as base class
    bool approx_equal(const Base& other, double tolerance) const;
    // .....................^^^^  method accept Base
};
```

A possible solution is relax the test in `HasApproxEqualMethod` to accept also  objects of different classes

```
template <class T, class U>
static std::true_type testSignature(bool (T::*)(const U&, double) const);
// now class and argument are different...^...........^
```

This way is satisfied also

```
static_assert(HasApproxEqualMethod<Derived>().value == true, "fail Derived");
```

If you want avoid at all the signature check, you can try something similar

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto haemHelper (T const &, int)
   -> decltype( &T::approx_equal, std::true_type{} );

template <typename T>
constexpr std::false_type haemHelper (T const &, long);

template <typename T>
using HasApproxEqualMethod = decltype( haemHelper(std::declval<T>(), 0) );
```

but, this way, `HasApproxEqualMethod<T>` is `std::true_type` also when `T` has a `approx_equal` method with a completely different signature or also when `approx_equal` is a simple member (a variable).

Answer (score 8):

What about using [`std::is_member_function_pointer_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer) (requires c++17):

```
// Works
static_assert(std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&Base::approx_equal)>); 
// Works
static_assert(std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&Derived::approx_equal)>); 
// Fails as expected
static_assert(!std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&Other::approx_equal)>);
```

You can shorten it like this:

```
template<typename Class> 
constexpr bool has_approx_equal()
{
    return std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&Class::approx_equal)>; 
}

static_assert(has_approx_equal<Base>()); 
static_assert(has_approx_equal<Derived>()); 
static_assert(!has_approx_equal<Other>());
```

**Final solution** uses SFINAE so that the compilation doesn't abort when tring to evaluate `&Other::approx_equal`:

```
template<typename Class, typename Enabled = void> 
struct has_approx_equal_s
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;  
};

template<typename Class> 
struct has_approx_equal_s
<
    Class, 
    std::enable_if_t
    <
        std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&Class::approx_equal)>
    > 
> 
{
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&Class::approx_equal)>; 
};

template<typename Class> 
constexpr bool has_approx_equal()
{
    return has_approx_equal_s<Class>::value; 
};

static_assert(has_approx_equal<Base>()); 
static_assert(has_approx_equal<Derived>()); 
static_assert(has_approx_equal<Other>(), "Other doesn't have approx_equal.");
```

SFINAE makes sure it is possible to get `false` value before trying to evaluate the static assertion.

Comment: Note that this approach only works if the method isn't overloaded. If you add a second `approx_equal` method to `Derived`, `has_approx_equal` won't detect either of them because `decltype(&Class::approx_equal)` becomes ambiguous. I have yet to find a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

> check if a method of a given name exists in a c++ class using c++11 features, but without(!) checking the signature.
>
> [..]
>
> In the end, I want to construct a template comparison function that calls approx_equal if it exists

In fact, you want to know if `bool(lhs.approx_equal(rhs, some_double))` is valid, so not exact signature, but "compatible" signature. and it is use to dispatch along overloads.

So, you may use `decltype` and order your overloads:

```
// helper function to prioritize overload. bigger has more priority
template <std::size_t N> struct overload_priority : overload_priority<N - 1> {};
template <> struct overload_priority<0> {}; // Lowest priority

// member function
template <typename T>
auto generic_approx_equal_impl(const T& lhs, const T& rhs, double tolerance, overload_priority<2>)
-> decltype(bool(lhs.approx_equal(rhs, tolerance))
{
    return lhs.approx_equal(rhs, tolerance);
}

// free function
template <typename T>
auto generic_approx_equal_impl(const T& lhs, const T& rhs, double tolerance, overload_priority<2>)
-> decltype(bool(approx_equal(lhs, rhs, tolerance))
{
    return approx_equal(lhs, rhs, tolerance);
}

// fallback
template <typename T>
bool generic_approx_equal_impl(const T& lhs, const T& rhs, double tolerance, overload_priority<0>)
{
    /*..*/
    //return abs(lhs - rhs) < tolerance;
    return false;
}

template <typename T>
bool generic_approx_equal(const T& lhs, const T& rhs, double tolerance)
{
    // Call with number greater or equal to max overloads
    return generic_approx_equal_impl(lhs, rhs, tolerance, overload_priority<10>{});
}
```